# Where is the bam portal

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-bam

I am trying to access the BAM on my server, but I can't find where it's located.
I know there's a way to access it via a web interface, but I can't find the url, anyone knows where I can find this url?

Is the bam portal supposed to be installed on the server with biztalk installed on it, or the one with the database installed on it?

Also, I've seen that some people use the BAM eventbus to acces the BAM, but they all point me to the administration console and it does not show up in mine. Does anyone know how I can make it show up?

I am using BizTalk Server 2006, and yes BAM is installed as I am logging events to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the BizTalk Configuration wizard. If BAM is configured, you should see where the database and portal are located.

Answer (score 1):

Its installed on your BizTalk server, not your database Server.

FWIW, in 2009 and 2010, if you did choose to install the BAM portal (as per Fabio's answer), then a shortcut appears under BizTalk Server on the program files. You can also look under your IIS configuration - by default, it is installed as the `BAM` application under your default web site (i.e. `http://localhost/BAM` will be the default)